# gRPC and Broken Pipe

Tags: python, pycharm, grpc

The question is about gRPC and broken Pipe.

I have write a client/server using GRPC. The server and client are all in my own computer, thus the address are all `127.0.0.1`, server's port is `8888`, client connect to `127.0.0.1:8888`. They work successful firstly. However, a `broken pipe` error suddenly occur.

Then I change my port from `8888` to `56789`, it works successfully again. But I don't know why `8888` isn't work, and always raise `Broken Pipe`.

The IDE I use is PyCharm, I used Python.

```py
channel = '127.0.0.1:8888'
conn = grpc.insecure_channel(channel)
client = RTCAutomationSDKStub(channel=conn)
```

```py
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/unittest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Exception calling application: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1612683917.302241000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8888","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1068,"grpc_message":"Exception calling application: [Errno 32] Broken pipe","grpc_status":2}"
>
```

I have try my best to solve it, but I can't find the answer.